# pydirectinput & pyautogui inhibiting keyboard input while script running

Tags: python, pyautogui

```
import time
import pydirectinput

pydirectinput.click(button='right')
time.sleep(0.5)
pydirectinput.click(button='right')
time.sleep(0.5)
```

This script simply presses right click every half second. However, while the script is waiting for the sleep to execute it seems that my keyboard inputs are blocked or delayed. I want to be able to move around in games while the script presses right click for me. Why would a sleep statement affect my keyboard inputs here and is there a better sleep alternative?

Comment: I've answered a similar question in the past. Does the mouse lag while `time.sleep`?

Comment: No, I don't notice any mouse lag - just keyboard.